# Nokia X 304 - The package name extracted from an APK file does not match the package name specified in the content item

Tags: nokiax

So the Quick, default publish app option did not work (which is a serious getting started / user experience issue). So I tried the standard option.

After I uploaded the app, I get this error

> Errors
>   304 - The package name extracted from an APK file does not match the package name specified in the content item.

Now, this happens because I have the following development environment

1. Android Library project with packagename com.mcruiseon.caregiri
2. A Android project dependent on 1), with packagename in the manifest as com.mcruiseon.caregirihindjewadibeta

When I upload the app, I guess your validation extracts the file, compares the actual packagename of class files, with the androidmanifest file and comes up with this conflict.

Why do I have this setup ? Its called multiple builds project supported by Android (http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html) My scenario is that I am building a carpool app, and I will use the same source code to build a bike pool app. And the same code base to build a demo app (marketing / sales buys can use to demonstrate to people on the road and in road shows). Its like the preprocessor directive thingy in C #ifdef.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt it matters what java package you use for your classes.

I think you have made a typo entering the package name for the application metadata during publishing. You can verify the packagename of your apk with the *aapt* command (it's located in you *Android SDK/build-tools/[version]/aapt*) by running:

```
$ aapt d badging YOURAPPLICATION.apk
package: name='com.mcruiseon.caregirihindjewadibeta' versionCode='1' versionName='1.0.0'
...
```

Use the *name* attribute there (I assume it will be *com.mcruiseon.caregirihindjewadibeta*) as the *Package name* of your content item during publishing.